# Distributed consensus feasibility from graph structure

Tags: graphs, distributed-systems

Consider a consensus process in which participants

1. Initially take a position
2. Receive positions only from their neighbors
3. Accept a new position that is a super-majority of neighbors positions.

Under what conditions is it possible for any participants to accept different new positions, regardless of whether they are neighbors?

More formally, consider a connected directed graph $G=(V,E)$ where vertices represent participants, and the  in-neighbors of a vertex $N(v) = \{u : (u,v) \in E\}$ represent the peers participant $v$ listens to.

Suppose there are $1,\ldots, K \leq |V|$ distinct positions and each node initially takes one position; i.e. $p(v,k)= 1 $ if node $v$ takes position $k$ and is 0 otherwise.

Each node tabulates the position votes of its neighbors and itself

$$o(v,k) = \frac{1}{|N(v)|+1}\left(p(v,k) + \sum_{u\in N(v)}p(u,k) \right)$$

From these votes, a node accepts a new position if $o(v,k) > t$.  It takes no position if $o(v,k) \leq t \forall k$.  Assuming a threshold $t > 0.5$, there can be at most one $k$ such that $o(v,k) > t$.  Let $f(v) \in \{0,\ldots,K\}$ be the accepted position of node $v$, with $0$ indicating the no accept case.

I'm interested in exploring how the properties of $G$ and the value of $t$ impact when it is possible for disagreement in the final outcome $f(v) \neq f(u) \neq 0$ for at least one pair $u,v$.

If the graph is fully connected, the peers must agree since they perform the same operation.  If the graph is not connected, then the independent components don't communicate and can clearly diverge.

I've struggled formulating this as a feasibility test for a binary linear program, but haven't figured out a way to use the structure of this problem to make it tractable.